# Make a trigger work for only a certain type of object

Tags: unity, c#

Is there a way you can make a trigger only exist to a certain type of objects while excluding other ones. I don't think the code will help but I just put anyway.

```
public class Girl : MonoBehaviour {

    public Attacker attacker;
    public Animator anim;
    public float girlHealth;
    public GameObject obj;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        attacker = GetComponent<Attacker>();
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();


    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (!obj)
        {
            anim.SetBool("isattacking", false);
        }
    }
   void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        obj = collision.gameObject;

        if (obj.tag == "Axe") {
            anim.SetBool("isattacking", false);
            anim.SetTrigger("ifAx");
        }

        if (obj.tag == "Stone") {
            anim.SetBool("isattacking", true);
        }
        if (obj.tag == "ActiveDefender")
        {
            anim.SetBool("isattacking", true);
        }



    }


}
```

I figured out a way to do it

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Attacker))]
public class Girl : MonoBehaviour {

    public Attacker attacker;
    public Animator anim;
    public float girlHealth;
    public GameObject obj;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        attacker = GetComponent<Attacker>();
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();


    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        if (!obj)
        {
            anim.SetBool("isattacking", false);
        }

    }
   void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {

       if(collision.gameObject.tag == "Stone")
        {
            obj = collision.gameObject;
        }
       else if (collision.gameObject.tag == "ActiveDefender")
        {
            obj = collision.gameObject;
        }


         if (obj.tag == "Stone") {
            anim.SetBool("isattacking", true);
        }
         else if (obj.tag == "ActiveDefender")
        {
            anim.SetBool("isattacking", true);
        }
        Debug.Log(collision.gameObject);

    }
    void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D collision)
    {

    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to GDSE! Here, when a question is "solved" we "accept" the most relevant answer. In your case, you should write an answer with the code that fixed your issue, and accept it. The "solved" part of your title is useless, as the interface of stack exchange sites is designed to recognize accepted (solved) answers.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the layer of the objects that you want to trigger with each other so that they are not on the default layer anymore (like all the other objects of your scene I assume). If you decide to create 2 different layers for instance if your interactions are a bit more complex), you will have to make those layers collide in the Collision matrix as well (under Edit > Project Settings > Physics 2D). Here is what you can find on Unity: [Physics Best Practices](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/physics/physics-best-practices?playlist=17120)

Depending on the type/characteristics of the objects that you want to trigger, you may want to check the following link on Unity website [Colliders](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html) in particular the section entitled

> Collision action matrix

Comment: Yeah, but I only want the Axe to know that it has hit the girl But I don't want the girl to know that the ax has hit her. If I use the collision matrix I am disabling it from both sides.

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure to get your issue. If you attached a script on the Axe with OnTriggerEnter2D checking that the collider is the girl. then the Axe will know when it hits a girl. If on the script attacherd to the girl, you don't check the condition that the collider belongs to the Axe, then the girl will not "know" that it has been hit by an axe.